# Flink SQL INSERT INTO query results in java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused error

Tags: sql, apache-flink, flink-sql

I am trying to run an `INSERT INTO` query on the Flink SQL Shell but keep running into this error (other queries using commands like `CREATE` and `ALTER` work, however). I've tried changing my port and IP address to see if that was the issue, but it keeps persisting (even though commands like `telnet` show a successful connection for those port and IP address combinations.

The query is trying to insert into a new table that has all the same columns as the table it is loading from. However, its connector type is different (i.e. the table that is being inserted into is of 'connector' = 'filesystem' whereas the other is not). I've tried using `SELECT *` and `SELECT` with each of the columns but still am getting the error. All the queries creating said tables said the execute statement succeeded and I was able to create views of the table that I'm loading from.

Any help or general guidance would be much appreciated - thanks!

Checked port connections using telnet and had successful connections that were being used (also listed as listening). Also, I checked for a backlog of servers but didn't see that either.

Comment: Hi - you should really include details of the specific query (or queries) that are failing.  It could be that the error message itself is a bit of a red herring (especially given you are saying that other queries complete successfully)